# FreeBSD - using pyvirtualdisplay - Python 2.7 / Selenium Web Driver

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, freebsd, pyvirtualdisplay

Below is the code am writing in FreeBSD. Before this code, I did

```
pkg install xorg-vfbserver
```

but after this I don't know which environment variable to set. Like in Ubuntu you have to do like this before using this program

```
apt-get install xvfb
export DISPLAY = :1
```

In FreeBSD, what is the environment variable to set ?
I read USES = DISPLAY but I couldn't understand as there isn't much of information about it. And because of that the Firefox starts and closes

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

try:
        display = Display(visible=0, size=(800,600))
        display.start()
except:
        print "no virtual display found"


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('www.google.com')

driver.close()
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1):

Installing X Virtual Frame

```
 sudo pkg install xorg-vfbserver
 sudo pkg install xkeyboard-config
 sudo pkg install xkbcomp
 sudo pkg instal x11-fonts/xorg-fonts
```

Firefox installation and machine-id generation

```
sudo pkg install firefox
dbus-uuidgen > machine-id
sudo mv machine-id /etc/
```

Depening on shell below are for bash. Better it in .bashrc or .cshrc file so that whenever you start a new terminal environment variable DISPLAY is set

```
export DISPLAY=:1
```

and in case of tcsh. Sometimes tcsh is default shell in FreeBSD

```
setenv DISPLAY :1
```

Start Xvfb and send it in background

```
nohup Xvfb :1 -screen 0 800x600x16 &
```

Now you don't even need to use pyvirtualdisplay in python. Just use webdriver.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
driver.close()
```